# Inserting into database LINQ to SQL Visual Basic Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql, linq, visual-studio-2008, ssms-2012

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

So i have a text box and a button, I would like to type something into the text box and have it inserted into a specific table when i click the button. Here is what i have so far.

I found something a lot easier to read

```
 Public Shared Sub InsertDealer(ByVal DealerName As String, _
                                ByVal DealerState As String)

    Dim dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext


    Try

        Dim cust As New tblDealer With {.DealerName = "John", _
 .DealerState = "TX"}
        dc.tblDealers.InsertOnSubmit(cust)
        dc.SubmitChanges()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

End Sub
```

error is "tblDealer is not defined"

Thanks

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Im getting a blue underline error under "Table(Of Dealer)" and "Dealer"

its saying their types are not defined

Comment: What is the name of the table in the SQL Server database?

Comment: tblDealer is the name of the table

Comment: Your updated code works for me.  With a table named tblDealer with an id, DealerName and DealerState columns

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you need to add the namespace to the tblDealer or us Imports to import the namespace.

```
Dim cust As New DataworldDataContext.tblDealer With {.DealerName = "John", _
    .DealerState = "TX"}
```